# How to pass custom argument via submit callback function in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, callback

This is my callback function with custom parameter.

```
function successCallback(form, action, customParam){
    if(customParam == '1'){
        // do xxx
    }
    else if(customParam == '2'){
        // do yyy
    }
    else {
        // do zzz
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea to pass custom value via ExtJS submit configuration ?

```
myForm.getForm().submit({
    url: 'http://mysite.com/target',
    method: 'POST',
    success: successCallback(9), // ??
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, just use this:

```
...
success : successCallback
...
```

The **successCallback** function will be called with all those parameters.

In future, use [createDelegate](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Function) for callback functions with parameters and scope.

```
...
success : function(){
    successCallback.createDelegate(param1, param2)();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In general: http://www.terrainformatica.com/2006/08/delegates-in-javascript-now-with-parameters/

in particular:

```
  ...
  success: function() { successCallback(1,2,3); } , 
  ...
```